# Java Crypto AES/GCM/NoPadding works on Windows but not on Docker (AEADBadTagException)

Tags: java, docker, encryption

I implemented a straight simple Java utility class to encrypt and decrypt using AES/GCM/NoPadding. I use this piece of code:

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] input, byte[] key, byte[] iv) throws Exception{
        Cipher cipher = initAES256GCMCipher(key, iv, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE);
        return cipher.doFinal(input);
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] input, byte[] key, byte[] iv) throws Exception{
        Cipher cipher = initAES256GCMCipher(key, iv, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
        return cipher.doFinal(input);
}

private Cipher initAES256GCMCipher(byte[] key, byte[] iv, int encryptionMode) throws Exception{
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);

        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(encryptionMode, secretKey, gcmParameterSpec);
        return cipher;
}
```

IV is always a 12-byte array, key is 32-byte array **generated with SecureRandom taking a seed**. I knowthat on different OS SecureRandom is different, but encryption and decryption are performed on the same OS, so there should be no problem.

Is it quite linear, right? It works perfectly on Windows, ciphering and deciphering return the same text. However, on a Docker image, the same JAR doesn not work: encryption works fine, but decryption throws "AEADBadTagException".

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do not use `SecureRandom` to derive a key.** You'd use a Key Derivation Function (KDF) such as [HKDF](https://github.com/patrickfav/hkdf) to do that. But honestly, you have to think of a way to communicate the key - *without* using `SecureRandom`.

The problem is that the - relatively secure - SHA1PRNG algorithm is not well defined. The SUN provider does accept a seed that is then used as an *only* seed **iff** you seed it before retrieving any random data from it. However, it makes sense that other providers will just **mix in** the seed to the state of the underlying CSPRNG. This is also the default for most other `SecureRandom` implementations.

Few `SecureRandom` implementations fully specify the way that random bits are returned even if the underlying algorithm is specified (with the DRBG). That is usually not a problem if you are just expecting random values. However, if you are using it as a deterministic algorithm such as a KDF (or hash function, for instance) then this becomes a problem and you may get different keys for the same input.

Nowadays you should be able to *store* AES secret keys within a key store. Not sure if that is a solution for your use case, but it should solve your current issue. Unfortunately Java doesn't contain any official KDF's other than PBKDF1 and PBKDF2 which takes a password rather than a key. Just using a HMAC-SHA256 over some key identifying data using a master key is commonly a good "poor mans KDF".

---

Here is a quick, initial (but undocumented) implementation that I just created. It mimics the Java JCA without actually going into implementation (as [no specific KDF class is defined for it, yet](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8189808)).

You can ask many keys from it with any algorithm specification, as long as the size is below 256 bits (the output of SHA-256) and the label is different for each key that you request. Call `getEncoded()` on the key if you need data for, for instance, an IV.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import hex.Hex;

public class PoorMansKDF {

    public interface KeyDerivationParameters extends AlgorithmParameterSpec {
        String getDerivedKeyAlgorithm();
        int getDerivedKeySize();
        byte[] getCanonicalInfo();
    }

    public static class KeyDerivationParametersWithLabel implements KeyDerivationParameters {

        private final String algorithm;
        private final int keySize; 
        private final String label;

        public KeyDerivationParametersWithLabel(String algorithm, int keySize, String label) {
            this.algorithm = algorithm;
            this.keySize = keySize;
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getCanonicalInfo() {
            if (label == null) {
                // array without elements
                return new byte[0];
            }
            return label.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }

        @Override
        public String getDerivedKeyAlgorithm() {
            return algorithm;
        }

        @Override
        public int getDerivedKeySize() {
            return keySize;
        }
    }

    private enum State {
        CONFIGURED,
        INITIALIZED;
    }

    public static PoorMansKDF getInstance() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        return new PoorMansKDF();
    }

    private final Mac hmac;
    private State state;

    private PoorMansKDF() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        this.hmac = Mac.getInstance("HMACSHA256");
        this.state = State.CONFIGURED;
    }

    public void init(Key key) throws InvalidKeyException {
        if (key.getAlgorithm().equalsIgnoreCase("HMAC")) {
            key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "HMAC"); 
        }

        hmac.init(key);
        this.state = State.INITIALIZED;
    }

    public Key deriveKey(KeyDerivationParameters info) {
        if (state != State.INITIALIZED) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not initialized");
        }

        final int keySize = info.getDerivedKeySize();
        if (keySize < 0 || keySize % Byte.SIZE != 0 || keySize > hmac.getMacLength() * Byte.SIZE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Required key incompatible with this KDF");
        }
        final int keySizeBytes = keySize / Byte.SIZE;

        // we'll directly encode the info to bytes
        byte[] infoData = info.getCanonicalInfo();
        final byte[] fullHMAC = hmac.doFinal(infoData);
        final byte[] derivedKeyData;
        if (fullHMAC.length == keySizeBytes) {
            derivedKeyData = fullHMAC;
        } else {
            derivedKeyData = Arrays.copyOf(fullHMAC, keySizeBytes);
        }

        SecretKey derivedKey = new SecretKeySpec(derivedKeyData, info.getDerivedKeyAlgorithm());
        Arrays.fill(derivedKeyData, (byte) 0x00);
        if (fullHMAC != derivedKeyData) {
            Arrays.fill(fullHMAC, (byte) 0x00);
        }
        return derivedKey;
    }

    // test only
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        var kdf = PoorMansKDF.getInstance();
        // input key (zero byte key for testing purposes, use your own 16-32 byte key)
        // do not use a password here!
        var masterKey = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[32], "HMAC");
        kdf.init(masterKey);

        // here "enc" is a label, in this case for a derived key for ENCryption 
        var labeledParameters = new KeyDerivationParametersWithLabel("AES", 256, "enc");
        var derivedKey = kdf.deriveKey(labeledParameters);
        // use your own hex decoder, e.g. from Apache Commons
        System.out.println(Hex.encode(derivedKey.getEncoded()));

        var aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        var gcmParams = new GCMParameterSpec(128, new byte[12]);
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, derivedKey, gcmParams);
        var ct = aesCipher.doFinal();
        System.out.println(Hex.encode(ct));
    }
}
```