# How can I generate my key to decrypt files that I encrypted with a key that I generated with this code?

Tags: java, android, cryptography, sha1

```
public static byte[] generateKey(String password) throws Exception
    {
        byte[] keyStart = password.getBytes("UTF-8");

        KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
        sr.setSeed(keyStart);
        kgen.init(128, sr);
        SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
        return skey.getEncoded();
    }
```

On Android 5.1 it worked perfectly, I would like to recover my files, how to decrypt them on Android 11?

Comment: This may not be possible. There is no guarantee that implementations for SHA1PRNG are identical across platforms and even versions. For key derivations, key derivation functions like PBKDF2 or the more modern Argon2 should be used, but not SecureRandom/SHA1PRNG, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60118857/9014097).